# Laravel Class 'Gate' not found

Tags: laravel-5, authorization, laravel-5.1

I have follow the [upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.11) but I can't manage to make the Authorization work.

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    /*protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];*/


    protected $policies = [
        Request::class => AnalysisPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);

        //
    }
}
```

**Analysis policy**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Policies;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use App\User;
use App\Request;

class AnalysisPolicy
{
use HandlesAuthorization;

/**
 * Create a new policy instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}


public function view(Request $analysis){

    return true;

}


//
```

}

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;


abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

**TestController**

```
 public function showTest()
    {
        $analysis= Request::find(1);


        return view('test', ['analysis' => $analysis]);
    }
```

**Test.blade.php**

```
Test page


@can('view', $analysis)
    Hello world
@endcan
```

**config\app**

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,


],

'aliases' => [

    'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
    'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
    'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
```

I always get `Class 'Gate' not found`. I have laravel 5.1.23. I have tried to run `composer update` and `artisan clear-compiled` but nothing worked.

Comment: May I ask which version that you had before going through this upgrade guide instructions?

Comment: @MohamedKawsara I already had 5.1.23 but I never attempted to use the Authorization functions, which is the new feature of 5.1.11, before applying the upgrade guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

1. in
   `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider.php`
2. update the provider
   https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php